# Stop popup window to fill parameter in query

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox

I setup a textbox ("custlookup") which takes a business ID, then when I press the "Search/Update customer" button, it takes me to a previously created form to update that particular customer details, using a macro (On_Click) and in the where clause I specified the following:

```
WHERE = custlookup[Forms]![WelcomeMenu]![custlookup]=[CustomerFACT]![customer_id]
```

yet when I give an ID and press the "Search/Update customer" I get a popup window asking me to "enter parameter value" and I don't know why. In previous buttons (which do the same for in different forms) it works fine, AND RELY ON THE SAME "custlookup" textbox.
[image]

After cancelling the macro and trying in code:

```
Private Sub button7_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "loanupdateform", , , "[custlookup] = '" & [CustomerFACT]![cust_id] & "' And [LownFACT]![history_ind] ='" & True & "'"
End Sub
```

Comment: `"WHERE customer_id=" & Forms!WelcomeMenu!custlookup`

Comment: not working; I am using the macro builder and also, in another button which relies on the same "custlookup" textbox - it workd without a popup window...

Comment: Well maybe include more than just a where clause then... ? hard to guess without more information (in your question, not in a comment btw) Let's see the code you are using too.

Comment: @braX I added a picture in the question, I hopw it helps since most of it is in hebrew...

Comment: Posted expressions could never have worked in any instance. Expression in image is backwards. See @braX comment for correct syntax, essentially: fieldname = form control.

Comment: I am not an expert in access, but I have to stress again that I have a textbox where I fill a customer ID. Next, I have 2 buttons which use that customer Id - one to update customer details and another to update customer loan status. In the first button everything works fine while in the second one, after inserting the customer ID and pressing the button a popup window opens which asks me to fill an value, again...

Comment: Wait, If db is Hebrew and everything is right to left, does that mean even the SQL WHERE clause must be entered right to left? And the SQL engine properly executes? A popup prompt often means Access simply can't find the referenced object, usually due to a spelling error. If that is not the case, then really not likely issue can be resolved without direct review of db and SO does not allow attaching files. Question appears not suited to SO. Sometimes weirdness is due to corruption. Try building another button and see if issue replicates.

Comment: ok, I cancelled the macro and used vba code as such. now I am getting the error "MS Access connot find the field |1... I updated the question with the code. thanks

Comment: Why are you referencing two different tables in criteria? If history_ind is a yes/no field, don't put True between apostrophes, in fact, don't even need `=True`. If cust_id is a number field, don't use apostrophes. Try: `"[cust_id]=" & Me.custlookup & " And [history_ind]"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot; I realized that I compared custlookup[Forms]![WelcomeMenu]![custlookup]=[CustomerFACT]![customer_id] where I should have compared custlookup[Forms]![WelcomeMenu]![custlookup]=[LoanFACT]![customer_id]